# What does the Linux kernel do with unknown kernel parameters?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, init, initramfs, kernel-parameters

Supposedly I passed the kernel a parameter that it doesn't understand, for example `blabla` or `eat=cake`, what would the kernel do with these unknown parameters, the traditional case would be passing any unknown parameter to `init`, in case if the the Linux kernel starts with early user space (initramfs) would it pass it to `/init` in initramfs?

Comment: IIRC they just get ignored. TIAS.

Comment: @TomYan Nothing happens.

Comment: So you got your answer?

Comment: It seems that what you want to know is, which parts / are everything in the kernel command line passed to the init in the initramfs. I am not sure if all distro / init take similar approach but in Arch/mkinitcpio, the init has function that mount /proc (and more) and parse /proc/cmdline: https://git.archlinux.org/mkinitcpio.git/tree/init?h=v23#n13

Comment: @TomYan I got the answers for my questions by looking at `/init` in initramfs. In Ubuntu, initramfs is pretty much generic, the `/init` mounts `/proc` and `/devtmpfs` and also runs `udevd` and among many things it mounts the real root filesystem.  Everything is handled at user space. So initramfs in Ubuntu is pretty much complex. That's why I hate generic kernels, their complexity is just not worth it. I'd rather buy the hardware than spend a day trying to figure out something. Plus, having a specific hardware with the appropriate drivers, makes a perfect system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.rst):

> The kernel parses parameters from the kernel command line up to `--`;
>   if it doesn't recognize a parameter and it doesn't contain a `.`, the
>   parameter gets passed to init: parameters with `=` go into init's
>   environment, others are passed as command line arguments to init.
>   Everything after `--` is passed as an argument to init.

This also applies to `/init` on an initramfs. In the source code, both the initramfs's `/init` and the final root's `/sbin/init` (or other locations) are invoked via [`run_init_process`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/ident/run_init_process) which uses the same arguments (apart from argument 0 which is the path to the executable). I can't find it stated in the documentation but kernel interfaces are stable so this won't change.

Note that this does not apply to `/linuxrc` on an initrd. This one is invoked with no arguments, but with the same environment as `/init` and `/sbin/init`. It can mount the proc filesystem and read `/proc/cmdline` to see the kernel command line arguments.

Comment: For `/init` in initramfs, `/init` passed the parameters on to  `/sbin/init` and when I checked `/proc/1/cmdline` this is what I got:  `/sbin/initbbbbbb`. The path to the executable is there in addition to the unknown parameter.